# Dual screen kiosk mode in ChromeOS on Chromebox?

Tags: google-chrome-app

I've found a few places that talk about trying to extend a window between screens, have enabled the unified desktop tag, which didn't work.

I've also found a few places talking about doing this in Windows that use Win32 calls to do it, which is useless for ChromeOS.

All I need is to put a second web view on the second screen. It doesn't need to be an extended window. I just need to do something like this:

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
var screenOne = {
   'id': 'mainwin',
   'bounds': {
     'width': 768,
     'height': 1360
   }
};
    var screenTwo = {
   'id': 'secondwin',
   'bounds': {
     'left':768+768,
     'width': 768,
     'height': 1360
   }
 };
 chrome.power.requestKeepAwake("display");
 chrome.app.window.create('../index.html', (screenOne));
 chrome.app.window.create('../screen2/index.html', (screenTwo));
});
```

Also, bonus points on a solution that works in the simulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my solution, which works beautifully. It requires you to add `system.display` to the permissions object in manifest.json

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  var screenUrls = ['../index.html','../screen2/index.html'];
  chrome.system.display.getInfo(function(displays){
    for(var id in displays){
      var display = {
        id: displays[id].id,
        bounds:displays[id].bounds
      };

      chrome.app.window.create(screenUrls[id], display);
    }
   });
   chrome.power.requestKeepAwake("display");
});
```

Comment: Anyone tried this with chrome extension? 

Scenario where I am having the issue - After the receiving the message from PWA, the chrome extensions chrome.windows.create does return a window object but in reality doesnt create a window. I have tried with top:0, left:1920 (width of screen 1, so that second window opens on the secondary monitor) Also after creating the window when I query chrome.windows.getAll() it only returns one window object (the original PWA app window) and this has different ID than the one return by create function.